# Representing decimal numbers in binary

Tags: math, logic, byte, logical-operators

How do I represent integers numbers, for example, 23647 in two bytes,  where one byte contains the last two digits (47) and the other contains the rest of the digits(236)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways do to this.

One way is to try to use [Binary Coded Decimal (BCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). This codes decimal digits, rather than the number as a whole into binary. The packed form puts two decimal digits into a byte. However, your example value `23647` has five decimal digits and will not fit into two bytes in BCD. This method will fit values up to `9999`.

Another way is to put each of your two parts in binary and place each part into a byte. You can do integer division by `100` to get the upper part, so in Python you could use

```
upperbyte = 23647 // 100
```

Then the lower part can be gotten by the modulus operation:

```
lowerbyte = 23647 % 100
```

Python will directly convert the results into binary and store them that way. You can do all this in one step in Python and many other languages:

```
upperbyte, lowerbyte = divmod(23647, 100)
```

You are guaranteed that the lowerbyte value fits, but if the given value is too large the upperbyte value many not actually fit into a byte. All this assumes that the value is positive, since negative values would complicate things.

---

(This following answer was for a previous version of the question, which was to fit a floating-point number like `36.47` into two bytes, one byte for the integer part and another byte for the fractional part.)

One way to do that is to "shift" the number so you consider those two bytes to be a single integer.

Take your value (36.47), multiply it by 256 (the number of values that fit into one byte), round it to the nearest integer, convert that to binary. The bottom 8 bits of that value are the "decimal numbers" and the next 8 bits are the "integer value." If there are any other bits still remaining, your number was too large and there is an overflow condition.

This assumes you want to handle only non-negative values. Handling negatives complicates things somewhat. The final result is only an approximation to your starting value, but that is the best you can do.

Doing those calculations on 36.47 gives the binary integer

```
10010001111000
```

So the "decimal byte" is `01111000` and the "integer byte" is `100100` or `00100100` when filled out to 8 bits. This represents the float number `36.46875` exactly and your desired value `36.47` approximately.